# Change TabBarController to Segmented Control

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

In the book iOS 5 Recipes, the Core Data chapter example has a 3-sectioned tab bar controller to choose which Entity of data (in TableView format) you want to add to with the + button on the navigation bar & want to view.  I want a 3-sectioned segmented control for the same purpose but at the top. I don't have a say in this. The original code uses only 1 view controller, but creates 3 different ivars (one for each section). The 3 entities are Teacher, Instrument & Student.

My biggest problem seems to be coding the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of the AppDelegate.

Here is the original code (AppDelegate.m):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self managedObjectModel]);
    self.teacherTable = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"%@", [self managedObjectModel]);
    self.teacherTable.entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Teacher" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.teacherTable.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.teacherTable.title = @"Teachers";

    self.studentTable = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.studentTable.entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.studentTable.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.studentTable.title = @"Students";

    self.instrumentTable = [[MainTableViewController alloc] init];
    self.instrumentTable.entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Instrument" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    self.instrumentTable.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    self.instrumentTable.title = @"Instruments";

    self.teacherNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.teacherTable];
    self.studentNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.studentTable];
    self.instrumentNavcon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.instrumentTable];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.teacherNavcon, self.studentNavcon, self.instrumentNavcon, nil]];

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Thanks for the help!